# Trying to insert data on Mysql with Python pyqt5

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to do a simple thing.
I have two fields a label (cod. client) that need receive the result of select query from Mysql of an auto-increment field and another field editline (name client) that need make a insert on db.
But I don't know where is the problem, could you help? Follow my code.

```
import MySQLdb
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="123456", db="test")
c = conn.cursor()


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def select(self):
        c.execute("SELECT id FROM client")

    def insert(self):
        c.execute('INSERT INTO client(name) values("%s")' % (self.nameClient))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(200, 200)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.labelCodClient = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget, self.select())
        self.labelCodClient.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 10, 75, 23))
        self.labelCodClient.setObjectName("labelCodClient")

        self.labelNameClient = QtWidgets.QLabel("Name Client", self.centralwidget)
        self.labelNameClient.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 60, 75, 23))
        self.labelNameClient.setObjectName("labelNameClient")

        self.nameClient = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.nameClient.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(75, 60, 75, 23))
        self.nameClient.setObjectName("nameClientInput")

        self.insertButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.insertButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 75, 23))
        self.insertButton.setObjectName("insertButton")
        self.insertButton.clicked.connect(self.insert())

        self.quitButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.quitButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(95, 100, 75, 23))
        self.quitButton.setObjectName("quitButton")
        self.quitButton.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.quitButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Quit"))
        self.insertButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Insert"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This instruction: `self.labelCodClient = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget, self.select())` expects select() to return a string but in your case it does not return anything

Comment: Also change `self.insertButton.clicked.connect(self.insert())` to `self.insertButton.clicked.connect(self.insert)`

Comment: Change `def select(self):
        c.execute("SELECT id FROM client")` to `def select(self):
        return c.execute("SELECT id FROM client")[0]`

Comment: Hi eyllanesc, firstly thx for reply!

This instruction: self.labelCodClient = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget, self.select()) expects select() to return a string but in your case it does not return anything

in this case, what is the correct do to?

Comment: Your table has some information saved?

Comment: No, is empty. When I run the code open a window to input some information in a name client field and I have a button Insert to record the data on Mysql. Well... I'm trying to do this in my mind... lol

Comment: then how do you expect something to return if it is empty?

Comment: The idea is... when calling the window need to come with client cod filled with a number of auto-increment field from db, and a field to input the information name and click on the button to save on db.

Comment: I think you have to read about the database, the auto-increment field increases every time a new data is inserted, it does not increase before!!!

Comment: Oh my God! I'm so stupid! Yeah, you are completely right!! I will try to do something to solve this problem. I don't know how to work with auto-increment fields. I'm a beginner in this area of programming then I need to think a little bit more to find a solution.

Comment: eyllanesc thank you very much for the help!

Comment: I give up... I never will understand how this stuff works! =(